# Does ROW_NUMBER affect performance?

Tags: sql-server, row-number

Is there a performance problem when using (ROW_NUMBER) function in getting a specific set of data?

Comment: As opposed to...?  Compared to `select *` or compared to some other method?

Comment: Way too broad,can you add more details?

Comment: Compared to select Top *

Comment: More information does require more operation, when ROW_NUMBER() requires ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Like always, you have to test it in your specific case, then you'll know for sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ultimate answer is to look at the query plan that is produced by a query with, and without, row_number. In practice row_number is such an effective clause that many feel (and have shown) that row_number seems to solve difficult problems (such as eliminating duplicates in table) more proficiently that any other method (start flame war here....). Since its introduction in SQL Server 2005 its become extremely popular for a reason. In general SQL Server orders tables very efficiently (once again dependent on the size of the table and if there is an index on the order by columns...).

But to restate the obvious it don't mean a thing until you look at the actual query plan that is produced with and without it.